# Upgrade to EE 2.10.1 - An Error Was Encountered Non-existent class: Template

Tags: error, ee2-upgrades

I successfully upgraded a site from EE 2.9.1 to 2.10.1, but when I go to the home page I get the following error:

> An Error Was Encountered Non-existent class: Template

I can access the control panel but I can't get past the error notice on public facing pages. I have searched and find only one old reference to this error. Can anyone shed light on the cause and solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that expressionengine/libraries/template.php was empty on the server. Something must have happened in transit that wiped the file clean. I uploaded a fresh copy and everything was a good as new.